# Determining type of variables not declared at top of Fortran subroutine

Tags: c++, types, fortran, fortran77

I am working with a legacy Fortran 77 code subroutine where the parameter types are not declared at the top of the code block.

Here is a snippet showing the very top of the subroutine.

```
   SUBROUTINE BPASS(F1,F2,F3,F4,SI,N,A,IERR)
   REAL * 4 A( N ),FV( 4 )
```

From the above, I think that `A` is an array of length `N` with type `REAL *4`, equivalent in size to a C `float`.  Alternately, `FV(4)` is an array of length `4` with type `REAL *4`.

However, what are the types of `F1,F2,F3,F4,SI,N,IERR`, if the types are not listed?  It appears that `N` should be an `integer`.

I need to know the types so that I can call the subroutine from C++ code.  Is there a Fortran convention for the types that are not declared?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default Fortran will assign the type `integer` to variables whose names begin with the letters `I,J,K,L,M,N` and type `real` to all other undeclared variables.

I agree with your parsing of the definitions of `A` and `FV`.

Modern Fortran provides the expression `implicit none` for ensuring that the default rules are not applied, but when working with old codes it's sometimes not possible to avoid familiarity with the old dark ways.

Comment: Thanks, High Performance Mark.  The code is very old, but it does indeed provides some useful functionality from a golden age of computing.

Comment: @NicholasKinar, an useful mnemonic to remember: `INteger` goes with `I-N`, other variables are the default `REAL` kind.

Answer (score 4):

In `FORTRAN77`, by default variables starting with  I, J, K, L, M, or N are `INTEGER`, otherwise they are `REAL`. `FORTRAN90`, and some variants of `FORTRAN77`, provide a mechanism to disable this by using `IMPLICIT NONE`.

Comment: I much prefer C/C++, but Fortran was indeed the language that greatly advanced human progress over the past century.

Comment: I like Fortran as well, particularly the nuances of the code and the language quirks discussed in this question.  There's a rather interesting website up on the origins of the Fortran language that makes me grin and bear the strangeness of some of its language constructs: http://www-03.ibm.com/ibm/history/ibm100/us/en/icons/fortran/.

Comment: Fortran was one of the first languages I learned over 30 years ago, and I am glad to see that this effective language is still being used today.